# OpenNi/NITE : Segmentation fault with openni_tracker

Tags: ros, openni, nite

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am currently using the openni_tracker package to be able to track a person with a Kinect. I am working with Ubuntu 12.04 and ROS groovy.

I managed to install the package and I needed to install NiTE v1.5.2.21 to make it work (see this ticket : http://answers.ros.org/question/42654/openninite-incompatible-in-fuertegroovy-on-precise/)

But the program crashes with a segmentation fault when :

- you start the user tracker program
- identify at least two persons.
- end and restart the program.

I run it with gdb and got these informations about the error :

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fffe6e1ee56 in Segmentation::detectionByPoint(bool, std::vector<Vector2D<int>, std::allocator<Vector2D<int> > > const*) ()
   from /usr/lib/libXnVFeatures_1_5_2.so
```

I found the same error last year in this ticket : (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/openni-dev/259RT7dVSy4/tz1mwiFgejEJ)
But nobody seems to had a solution by this time, except removing the NITE library libXnVFeatures_1_5_2.so, and I would like to avoid this solution...

Does someone have some news/solutions about this problem ?

Caroline

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62873/openni/nite-:-segmentation-fault-with-openni_tracker/) by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 395 on 2013-05-15

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) on 2013-05-16**:
In order to be able to help you, people need you to precise your distribution and your ROS version :-)
Bests regards, Steph

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-05-16**:
Sorry I forgot this information. I just added it in the post. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have run into a similar (maybe the same issue). One big problem is, that the Nite developers are now focusing on their new versions (Nite 2.0+ included in OpenNI 2.0). So, for the time being we need to live with the current limitations. I'd like to see OpenNI 2.0 integrated into ROS soon. I hope a bunch of issues will get solved by that.

Maybe we can get enough people together to speed up this migration process.

PS: I solved my problem by re-plugging the Xtion every time it happened - not a nice solution ...

---

Originally posted by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) with karma: 2062 on 2013-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-06-19**:
Thansk for the answer, I hope the integration of OpenNI 2.0 into ROS will be done soon.
I also tested this solution of re-plugging the Xtion, but as you said it's not really a good solution...

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-06-20**:
@CarolineQ looks like there has been some progress: https://github.com/ros-drivers/openni_camera/issues/15 Maybe we can except something new soon!